# Sort a character array in ascending order using Counting sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, ascii, counting-sort

```
Input char a[10] = {'c','b','c','d','E','C','a','A','b','C'};
```

Output : A a b b C C c c d e

I have been given a character array and I have to sort it in ascending order and I **must** use **Counting sort** to do that

I have tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RANGE 255


void countingSort(char a[], char b[], int n) // a = array, b = empty array, n = size
{
    int i;

    int c[RANGE +1];
    memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));


    for( i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] + 1;
    }
    for(i = 1; i<RANGE; i++)
    {
        c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1];
    }
    for(i = n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        b[c[a[i]] - 1] = a[i];
        c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] - 1;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char a[10] = {'c','b','c','d','E','C','a','A','b','C'};
    int n = 10;
    char b[10];
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    countingSort(a,b,n);
    for( i = 0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have used ASCII table to sort the array and my output is

```
ACCEabbccd
```

I managed to sort the array in ascending order but I DO NOT know how to put a right after A and so on.

Comment: Must `countingSort()` be used unedited and than apply code after calling `countingSort()`  OR can `countingSort()` change?

Comment: countingSort() can be edited but it has to be in the program. Actually we are learning counting sort algorithm in class, so we need to implement it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach simply doubles the `c[]` size and forms an index where all even indexes are uppercase and odd ones are lowercase.

```
#if 1
#define RANGE (255*2 + 1)
#include <ctype.h>
#define CH_TO_INDEX(ch) \
    (2*toupper((unsigned char)ch) + !!islower((unsigned char) ch))

#else
// Original
#define RANGE 255
#define CH_TO_INDEX(ch)    (ch)

#endif

void countingSort(char a[], char b[], int n) {
  int i;
  int c[RANGE + 1];
  memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] + 1;
    c[CH_TO_INDEX(a[i])]++;
  }
  for (i = 1; i < RANGE; i++) {
    c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
  }
  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // b[c[a[i]] - 1] = a[i];
    b[c[CH_TO_INDEX(a[i])] - 1] = a[i];
    // c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] - 1;
    c[CH_TO_INDEX(a[i])]--;
  }
}
```

Output

```
cbcdECaAbC
AabbCCccdE
```

---

A more complex `char --> index` could be had that does not double the size of `c[]`.  Such mappings tend to make assumptions that there are only letters A-Z.  Such a mapping may use an auxiliary mapping array:

```
unsigned char map[256] - {
    0, 1, 2, ...., 31, ' ', ... 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', ... 'Z', 'z', 
    ASCII characters after 'Z' and before 'a'
    ASCII characters after 'z', .... 255 };
```

---

OP requested

```
Output : A a b b C C c c d e
```

But based on `{'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'E', 'C', 'a', 'A', 'b', 'C'}`, I think OP wants

```
Output : A a b b C C c c d E
```

---

Note that original code fails when `a[i] < 0`.  Code needs re-work for negative `char`.  Re-code using `unsigned char`.